# Passing Parameters Commandbutton

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton, apex-param

I don't know what is wrong with the code, I read a lot about the commandbutton and param, but it doesn't work.

> The Debug shows me that the value of the MS_Item is Null.
>   07:44:00.0 (8771917)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|my MS_Item: null

PAGE:

```
<apex:page controller="clicktest">

    <apex:form>

    <apex:commandButton action="{!Stats_In}" value="click" reRender="">
        <apex:param name="MS_Item" value="MS_Item_45382" assignTo="{!MS_Item}" />
    </apex:commandButton>

    </apex:form>    

</apex:page>
```

CLASS:

```
public class clicktest {

    Public String MS_Item {get; set;}

    public PageReference Stats_In() {
        MedienServer_Stats__c sta = new MedienServer_Stats__c();
        sta.MS_Item__c = MS_Item;    
        System.debug('my MS_Item: ' +MS_Item);
        INSERT sta;
        RETURN NULL;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to be add a DummyID for reRedner.

```
<apex:page controller="clicktest">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Stats_In}" value="click" reRender="dummyId">
        <apex:param name="MS_Item" value="MS_Item_45382" assignTo="{!MS_Item}" />
    </apex:commandButton>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a dummy `panel` and `reRender` it. It will work.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="panel2">

</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:commandButton action="{!Stats_In}" value="click" reRender="panel2">
    <apex:param name="MS_Item" value="MS_Item_45382" assignTo="{!MS_Item}" />
</apex:commandButton>
```

Comment: I was trying to reproduce this but was not able to. But yes need to have reRender even if it is some dummy element.