I want to get rowid in vf page table . List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Controller class
public class BankDetailsController {
    public list<Bank__c> banklist {get;set;}
    public boolean displayPopup {get; set;} 
    public boolean displayPopupTwo{get;set;}
    public Integer amount{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}  
    public string holdername{get;set;}
    public string AccountNumber{get;set;}
    public Integer InitialAmount{get;set;}
    public Id selectedBankAccountId{get;set;}
   
    public boolean  displayPopupThree{get;set;}
    public string editedName{get;set;}
    public string editedholdername{get;set;}
    public string  editedAccountNumber{get;set;}
   
 
    public void showPopup() {        
        displayPopup = true;    
    }
    public void showPopupAddAmount()
    {
        system.debug('selectedBankAccountId>>>>'+selectedBankAccountId);
        displayPopupTwo = true;
        
    }
    public void showPopUpEdit()
    {
        displayPopupThree=true;
    }

    public BankDetailsController ()
    {
         banklist   = [select id,Name,Initial_Amount__c,Balance__c,Account_Holder_Name__c,Account_Holder_Address__c,Amount__c,Bank_Account_Number__c from Bank__c ];
    }
    public void createAccount()
    {
        Bank__c bank = new Bank__c();
        bank.Name = Name;
        bank.Account_Holder_Name__c = holdername;
        bank.Bank_Account_Number__c = AccountNumber;
        bank.Balance__c= InitialAmount;
        insert bank;
        BankDetailsController bankOne = new BankDetailsController();
        displayPopup = false;
        
    }
    public void addAmount()
    {
        
       
         Bank__c bank  = [select  name,Balance__c,Amount__c from Bank__c where Id =:selectedBankAccountId];
        
          system.debug('bank>>>>>'+bank);
          bank.Amount__c = amount;
          bank.Balance__c += amount;
          update bank;
        displayPopupTwo= false;
    }
    public void editBankAccount()
    {
        displayPopupThree = false;
        Bank__c bank  = [select Balance__c,Account_Holder_Name__c,Bank_Account_Number__c,Amount__c from Bank__c where Id =:selectedBankAccountId];
        bank.Name= editedName;
        bank.Account_Holder_Name__c = editedholdername;
        bank.Bank_Account_Number__c = editedAccountNumber;
        update bank;
    }
    public void deleteAccount(){
        system.debug('ID::'+selectedBankAccountId);
         Bank__c bank  = [SELECT Id FROM Bank__c where Id =: selectedBankAccountId];
        DELETE bank;
        
    }
 
}

.........................................................................................
vf page
<apex:page controller="BankDetailsController" lightningStylesheets="true" >  
    <!-- apex form start-->
   
    <apex:form id="form" > 
        <apex:pageBlock title="Inline page example" id="msg">   
        <!-- use apex:datatable with header and caption facet to display account information-->  
        <table border="1px" width="80%" style="page-break-inside:auto;">
            <tr>
                <th>Bank Name</th>  
              <th>Account holder Name</th>
                <th> Bank Account Number </th>
              <th>Balance</th>
               <th>Id</th>
               <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!banklist}" var="bank" >
            <tr>
                
                <td>{! bank.Name}</td>
                <td>{! bank.Account_Holder_Name__c}</td>
                 <td>{! bank.Bank_Account_Number__c}</td>
                 <td>{! bank.Balance__c}</td>
                 <td>{!bank.id}</td>
                 <td>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!DeleteAccount}"   reRender="BankDetailsController"  >
                        <apex:param name="accountId" value="{!bank.id}" assignTo="{!selectedBankAccountId}"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>

                    <apex:commandButton value="AddAmount" action="{!showPopupAddAmount}"    >
                        <apex:param name="accountId" value="{!bank.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedBankAccountId}"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                   
                    <apex:commandButton value="Edit"  action="{!showPopUpEdit}" >
                        <apex:param name="accountId" value="{!bank.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedBankAccountId}"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>    
        </table>

        <apex:commandButton value="Add Bank Account" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="BankDetailsController"/>    

     <apex:outputPanel id="BankDetailsController">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
                Name : <apex:inputText id="name" value="{!Name}" />  
                <apex:param assignto="{!Name}" name="param1" value="" /><br/>
                Account Holder Name : <apex:inputText id="name2" value="{!holdername}" />  
                <apex:param assignto="{!holdername}" name="param2" value="" /><br/>
                Bank Account Number  : <apex:inputText id="name3" value="{!AccountNumber}" />  
                <apex:param assignto="{!AccountNumber}" name="param3" value="" /><br/>
                Initial Amount : <apex:inputText id="name4" value="{!InitialAmount}" />  
                <apex:param assignto="{!InitialAmount}" name="param4" value="" /><br/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Create Account" action="{!createAccount}" rerender="form"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="BankDetailsControllerThree">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopupTwo}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopupTwo}">
                Add Amount : <apex:inputText id="amount" value="{!amount}" />  
                <apex:param assignto="{!amount}" name="param5" value="" /><br/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Add " action="{!addAmount}" rerender="BankDetailsControllerThree"/>
                </apex:outputPanel> 
                </apex:outputPanel>

                <apex:outputPanel id="BankDetailsControllerTwo">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopupThree}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopupThree}">
                
                Name : <apex:inputText id="editedname" value="{!editedName}" />  
                <apex:param assignto="{!editedName}" name="param6" value="" /><br/>
                Account Holder Name : <apex:inputText id="holder" value="{!editedholdername}" />  
                <apex:param assignto="{!editedholdername}" name="param7" value="" /><br/>
                Bank Account Number  : <apex:inputText id="accountnumber" value="{!editedAccountNumber}" />
                <apex:param assignto="{!editedAccountNumber}" name="param8" value="" /><br/>

                <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!editBankAccount}" rerender="BankDetailsControllerTwo"/>
                </apex:outputPanel> 
                </apex:outputPanel>
        
            </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

        <style type="text/css">
            .custPopup{
                background-color: white;
                border-width: 2px;
                border-style: solid;
                z-index: 9999;  
                left: 50%;
                padding:10px;
                position: absolute;   
                width: 500px;
                margin-left: -250px;
                top:100px;
            }
            .popupBackground{
                background-color:black;
                opacity: 0.20;
                filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 9998;
            }    
    
        </style>
        </apex:page>
    ```


welcome to SFSE. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. There's both not enough information to help you (e.g. where is the error occurring) and too much information (your pasted code contains irrelevant bits to your problem). Use [edit] and reduce the size to show a minimum viable reproducible example of the error.

Check out this answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187539/passing-parameters-commandbutton; The doc states that apex:param is not supported as a child of commandButton but adding a rerender= is a workaround
